# How can I disable automatic screen lock for Xfce4 on vnc?

Tags: xfce, desktop-environments, vnc

I have tightvnc server on my new ubuntu-22.04 machine and can use vnc.
VNC xstartup is configured to use Xfce4.
How can I disable the automatic screen lock of the Xfce4 window?
I tried setting 'Display Power Management' to 'off' in Applications->Settings->Power Manager menu, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you *disabled* Xfce screensaver?  ` xfce4-screensaver-preferences` as it *locks* the screen on inactivity (power manager you mention turns the screen off to save electricity!)

Comment: Hi, right it's the screensaver that I have to disable. so I did in application-settings-screensaver, turn 'enable screensaver' 'off'. Thank you. (if you write this in the answer, I'll pick it as the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you disabled Xfce screensaver?

`xfce4-screensaver-preferences` will let you control locking the screen on inactivity, and includes options to either leave the screen *blank* or use a graphic-screensaver (*which helped prevent **burn-in** if using a monitor where that was a risk; and long ago it used to be a major risk*).

The power management you mention turns the screen off to save electricity (*battery life etc*).